# c# sort list by between two values asc or desc

Tags: c#, sorting

Say I have a list of objects like this:

```
var products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product { Name = "First", Price = 275.99 });
products.Add(new Product { Name = "Second", Price = 333.66 });
products.Add(new Product { Name = "Third", Price = 2455.99 });
products.Add(new Product { Name = "Forth", Price = 450.00 });
```

And I have a value like this:

```
var lower = 500;
var upper = 1000;
var direction = "Asc";
```

Now I wish to use [`List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx) to sort the products by items between the 2 values, using the direction to specify if it's ascending or descending.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

---

## Update

I don't want to filter this list, I would like the matching products to be at the top of the list and the others to be at the bottom. If the direction is ascending I would epect:

```
Product { Name = "First", Price = 275.99 };
Product { Name = "Second", Price = 333.66 };
Product { Name = "Forth", Price = 450.00 };
Product { Name = "Third", Price = 2455.99 };
```

If I change the values to:

```
var lower = 300;
var upper = 1000;
var direction = "desc";
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
Product { Name = "Forth", Price = 450.00 };
Product { Name = "Second", Price = 333.66 };
Product { Name = "Third", Price = 2455.99 };
Product { Name = "First", Price = 275.99 };
```

I hope that makes sense

Comment: What is the desired output, please?

Comment: products.orderByDecending(x => x.Price) Is it work for you?

Comment: Use a WHERE to get values between Min and Max and then sort.

Comment: products.Where(x=>x.Price>=lower && x.Price<=upper).OrderBydecending(x => x.Price)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom `Comparer` to achieve that:

```
var lower = 300;
var upper = 1000;
var direction = "Asc";

Func<Product, bool> isInRange = p => p.Price >= lower && p.Price <= upper;

var byPricesInRangeComparer = Comparer<Product>.Create((x, y) => {
    var ret = 0;
    var xInRange = isInRange(x);
    var yInRange = isInRange(y);

    if (xInRange && !yInRange)
        ret = -1;
    else if (yInRange && !xInRange)
        ret = 1;
    else
        ret = x.Price >= y.Price ? -1 : 1;

    return direction == "Asc" ? ret : (0 - ret);
});

products.Sort(byPricesInRangeComparer);
```

(Judging by the desired outputs you posted, you also want to compare by the actual price in case both prices falls within the expected range)

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

So you want *all* the data, but if both items are *within* `[lower..upper]` range they should be in `direction` order; all the values that are *without* range should be at the end of the list in arbitrary order:

```
   products.Sort((left, right) => {
     if (left.Price >= lower && left.Price <= upper)
       if (right.Price >= lower && right.Price <= upper) // both within range
         return direction == "asc" 
           ?  left.Price.CompareTo(right.Price) 
           : -left.Price.CompareTo(right.Price) 
       else 
         return -1; // left within, right without range
     else if (right.Price >= lower && right.Price <= upper) 
       return 1; // left without, right within range  
     else 
       return 0; // both left and right are without the range (arbitrary order)
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

with a string it's not very intuitive, but

```
        Dictionary<string, Comparison<Product>> comparer = new Dictionary<string, Comparison<Product>>
        {
            ["asc"] = (a, b) => a.Price.CompareTo(b.Price),
            ["desc"] = (a, b) => b.Price.CompareTo(a.Price)
        };

        var lower = 500;
        var upper = 1000;
        var direction = "Asc";
        var trimmed = products.Where(p => p.Price >= lower && p.Price <= upper).ToList();
        trimmed.Sort(comparer[direction.ToLower()]);
```

[This is C#6, btw.]

**Edit**

One (inefficient) way would be to filter, sort the filter, make a new list;

```
var trimmed = products.Where(p => p.Price >= lower && p.Price <= upper).ToList();
var excluded = products.Except(trimmed);
trimmed.Sort(comparer[direction.ToLower()]);
products = new List<Product>(trimmed);
products.AddRange(excluded);
```

Comment: I have made an update to my question, this is a good response, but I don't want to filter out any products

Comment: `Dictionary<string, Comparison<Product>>` is not equal `Dictionary<string, Comparison<decimal>>` so it won't compile

Comment: @Toshi Yeah. Copy and paste error. I used decimal to verify. Fixing it

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = products.Where(x => x.Price >= lower && x.Price <= upper);

if(direction.ToLower() == "asc")
    result = result.OrderBy(x=>x.Price);
else
    result = result.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Price);
```

If your lower is 500 and upper is 1000 you should check between both of them.

Comment: this not considering the direction

Comment: @HakamFostok now it is fixed.

Comment: That's `OrderBy` not `List<T>.Sort` OP explicitly requires this method